# Is there a better way to change a UIBarButtonItem from Refresh to Stop in a UIWebView other than my implementation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, uitoolbar

The way I've been doing it for a few years is to simply create two toolbars, and set one or the other to hidden while the UIWebView loads. All of my toolbars and barbutton items are created in IB. I would like to make my implementation smaller if I can without this sort of "hack" I appreciate any help offered.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
#import "Web.h"

@interface  Web()

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *stopButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButtonRefreshToolbar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *forwardButtonRefreshToolbar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *backButtonStopToolbar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *forwardButtonStopToolbar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbarStop;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIToolbar *toolbarRefresh;

@end

@implementation Web

- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
    self.toolbarStop.hidden = NO;
    self.toolbarRefresh.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
    self.toolbarStop.hidden = YES;
    self.toolbarRefresh.hidden = NO;
    [self actualizeButtons];
}

- (void)actualizeButtons
{
    self.backButtonRefreshToolbar.enabled = [self.webView canGoBack];
    self.forwardButtonRefreshToolbar.enabled = [self.webView canGoForward];
    self.backButtonStopToolbar.enabled = [self.webView canGoBack];
    self.forwardButtonStopToolbar.enabled = [self.webView canGoForward];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this belongs on code review

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with based on the above help:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIToolbar *webToolbar;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *backButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *forwardButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *refreshButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *stopButton;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIBarButtonItem *flexibleItem;

- (void)toolbarButtons
{
    self.backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UIButtonBarArrowLeft.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goBack)];

    self.forwardButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UIButtonBarArrowRight.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(goForward)];

    self.backButton.enabled = [self.webView canGoBack];
    self.forwardButton.enabled = [self.webView canGoForward];

    self.flexibleItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                  target:nil
                                                                  action:nil];


    self.refreshButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh
                      target:self action:@selector(refreshWebView)];

    self.refreshButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

    self.stopButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemStop
                      target:self action:@selector(stop)];

    self.stopButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;

    if(self.webView.loading)
    {
        NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.backButton, self.forwardButton, self.flexibleItem, self.stopButton, nil];
        [self.webToolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: self.backButton, self.forwardButton, self.flexibleItem, self.refreshButton, nil];
        [self.webToolbar setItems:items animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Use a single `UIToolbar` instance, and call its `setItems:animated:` method with `animated:NO` whenever you need to swap which items are displayed. This should have the same visual effect as showing/hiding a pair of toolbars.

You could probably also just set the `possibleTitles` property on the relevant `UIBarButtonItem` when its title needs to change.